# Why an empty variable is used to display FOR Loop properly

Tags: for-loop

a FOR loop will be display by the following method.

```js
    <p id ="demo"></p>
<script>
var cars = ["Civics" , "Corola" , "Ford" , "Mercedeez" , "Pejaro"];
var i;
var text = "";
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)  {
  text += cars[i];
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

I want to ask that why the variable "text" is necessary to use. why we can not simply write like this   cars[i];

Comment: What would you expect `cars[i]` to do?

Comment: here cars are to be displayed by increment (++) method . and it is necessary to write code as ( text = text + cars[i] +"<br>"; ) . Why not simply type the code ( text = cars[i] + "<br>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the text variable to store value in it for each iteration.

You can also achieve same result by:

```
<p id ="demo"></p>
<script>
var cars = ["Civics" , "Corola" , "Ford" , "Mercedeez" , "Pejaro"];
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = cars.join ('');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`cars[i]` in every iteration of the loop reads different values of the array `cars` one by one. As per the question, the output needs to be a concatenation of the Strings represented by each `cars[i]`. This concatenated string needs to be stored somewhere.This is why an extra variable `text` is needed which keeps on getting longer and longer.

```
text = ""                   //i=0
text = "Civics"             //i=1 After 1st loop 
text = "CivicsCorola"       //i=2 After 2nd loop
text = "CivicsCorolaFord"   //i=3 After 3rd loop
...
```